# Should "ads" and "advertising" tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

- [advertising](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advertising) × 184 - the practice of producing text, images, or other media intended to influence others' purchasing decisions.
- [ads](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ads) × 60 - Short for advertisements. Visual elements added by a webmaster on a web site or web page to earn money.

Comment: Seeing no objections, I'm going ahead with this tag merge.

Answer (score 1):

These tags mean basically the same thing and should be merged.  The canonical tag should be "advertising" because it is used more and because "ads" is a short form of it.

Answer (score 1):

Missed this one...

My preference would have been to leave `advertising`, which is the *practice*, and `ads`, which are the *elements*, as separate tags.

Not sure if this can be reversed at this point however.