# Tag merge request: [advertising] and [advertisement]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Right now [advertising](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advertising) has 420 questions, and [advertisement](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advertisement) has 23 questions.

I propose we mark the latter as a synonym for the former, since afaik they mean the exact same thing.

This also has the added benefit of nobody being able to make any jokes about the number of [advertising](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advertising) questions, because I hate fun.

Comment: Update: Since there were no objections, the `advertisement` tag was merged with and made a synonym of the `advertising` tag. This should be fully visible in a day or so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/should-ads-and-advertising-tags-be-merged) related Meta discussion, the [ads](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ads) tag was made a [synonym](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) of the [advertising](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advertising) tag.

Though it seemed to be agreed there that [ads](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ads) was short for [advertisement](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advertisement), there isn't a synonym between the two however. Ergo, it seems logical that [advertisement](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advertisement) should also become a synonym of [advertising](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advertising).

In regards to `because I hate fun`, please note that *fun* is strictly considered off-topic here - JK :-)